# How can I implement a trait for iterators with different kinds of values?

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to create a trait that adds a method for all iterators of `(K: Ord, V)` tuples, and I want it to work whether the tuple is owned or borrowed. I ran into a problem where the compiler says there are conflicting implementations, and I don't understand why. Here is the minimal version of my code:

```
struct MyStruct<I> {
    iter: I
}

trait MyTrait<K: Ord, I> {
    fn my_func(self) -> MyStruct<I>;
}

impl<K: Ord, V, I: Iterator<Item=(K, V)>> MyTrait<K, I> for I {
    fn my_func(self) -> MyStruct<I> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl<'a, K: Ord, V, I: Iterator<Item=&'a (K, V)>> MyTrait<K, I> for I {
    fn my_func(self) -> MyStruct<I> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Given that `&'a(K, V)` has no overlap with `(K, V)`, I thought this should be fine. Why isn't this code valid, and how can it be changed to make it compile?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20400

Comment: @Aplet123 Yep, that's definitely it. Guess I just have to wait for the RFC to decide how they want to solve it, then wait for the solution, and then wait for that to go into the stable channel :/